# Fcm notification is not coming in android 4.4 having phones

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification

I followed the fcm tutorial from following link. [Fcm Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

When I send notifications through firebase console, the notifications are showing up on all devices. However, when I send a global notification or individual notifications using device registration ID from the PHP form from this tutorial, notifications are not showing up on Android phones running Android 4.4. Notifications are showing up perfectly on all Android phones having Android 6.0.

Many of the users facing the same issue. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you might try going to Settings -> Apps, then swipe right. There might be a tab there called "restricted". If there is, go to it, and then uncheck whatever apps you are using. This worked for me.

If there is any launcher app or battery saver app in kitkat4.4 Notification may be disabled ,you need to enable it.

Comment: I checked the app notification is checked. No additional applications installed because its my testing device. My devices are "acer iconia tab 7" , moto g 3g, HTC DESIRE 626GPLUS and oneplus one.. Notification coming in oneplus one and moto g 3g. In tab and htc notification is not coming. both are android 4.4. One plus one and motog are 6.0